# The Best method for attaining Krishna

Tags: bhagavad-gita, philosophy, yoga

In every Yoga of the Bhagvad Gita (especially from the Gitas I hear or read), Lord Krishna prescribes the superiority of that Yoga over the others. Which one is the best one in reality? Or is there any method prescribed for each person to be the best?

Comment: kindly read the chapter 12 from bhagwad gita where he himself answers, which way is the best way to attain him

Comment: https://vedabase.io/en/ Chant his name ask him He is sure to tell you the best way to attain him